# bootstrap css repeated items randomly skipped

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm repeating a list of items (`ng-repeat`) and there are seemingly randomly skipped spaces on the page that end up blank.

[image]

When I inspect element, the next div after Dr. Strauss is indeed Dr. Schimmel which leads me to believe there are no elements in the list that are not getting shown. I think it is then a css issue.

HTML:

```
<div class="row user-doctors">
    <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="doctor in doctors |limitTo: 9">
         <div class="card-white">
          <div class="img-wrapper">
            <div class="row" ng-show="doctor.recommend">
              <div class="col-md-12" 
                   tooltip="{{ userFirstName }} recommends Dr. 
                            {{ doctor.last_name }}" tooltip-placement="top">
                  <i class="fa fa-check recommend-icon"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
            <img src="{{doctor.photo_url}}" ng-click="goToDoctor(doctor)">
            <div class="text-container">
              <span>Dr. {{ doctor.last_name }}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"><i class="fa fa-medkit"></i></div>
            <div class="col-md-10">{{ doctor.city }}, {{ doctor.state }}</div>
            <div class="col-md-2"><i class="fa fa-stethoscope"></i></div>
            <div class="col-md-10">{{ doctor.specialty }}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
  .user-doctors {
    .card-white {
      margin: 20px;
      padding: 10px;
      .img-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        .recommend-icon {
          color: #5cb85c;
          position: absolute;
          right: 15px;
        }
      }
      img {
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 150px;
        height: auto;
      }
      .text-container {
        position: absolute;
        width: 95%;
        bottom: 0;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, .7));
        @extend .center;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        span {
          font-weight: bold;
          font-size: 14px;
          color: white;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
      }
      .col-md-10 {
        padding-left: 2px;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think the missing records are just because you have `ng-show="doctor.recommend"`, I'd rather say if you wanted to show doctor which are recommended then you should go for filter, where `ng-repeat="doctor in doctors | filter: {recommend: true} |limitTo: 9`

Comment: @PankajParkar ah, thank you. you are correct. I was able to remove the ng-show and there are no spaces. feel free to provide an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the hidden records are nothing but because of `ng-show="doctor.recommend"` condition which shows the element and occupy space, but just hide the inner content of it.

I'd rather suggest you to just using filter like which will show `recommend` doctor.

```
ng-repeat="doctor in doctors | filter: {recommend: true} |limitTo: 9
```

Comment: thanks. however, I do want to show doctors that aren't recommended. it's just the row that'd i'd like to conditionally include. I tried `ng-if` on the row but that did not help.

Comment: @user2954587 what you want to achieve in first place?

Comment: to show the checkbox conditionally on `doctor.recommend`

Comment: @user2954587 Ok..but then above code should work & what about `doctor.city`& other data which you shown on UI? is it appearing on HTML?

Comment: yes, all other info showing, just not the checkbox. If I remove the `ng-show` then all get the checkbox and there are no missing elements. I've also tried moving the various combinations of `ng-if` and `ng-show` but `ng-if` seems to include the elements in the DOM anyways

Comment: @user2954587 could you confirm that `doctor.recommend` has `bool` value ? by printing `{{doctor.recommend}}` on html or by debugging code.

Comment: confirmed it is a boolean value

Comment: @user2954587 it should work as intented, could you create plunkr or fiddle?